# Unknown field in MPI_status

Tags: mpi

I'm working with the MPI library, and while using a var type MPI_status, I tired to access the field count, but the compiler says it's not avaiable.
I found 2 different soucres - one claiming that the struct has a field named count, and the other claims that in has a field named size.
I've tried both, and both won't compile. any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node31.html

> In C, status is a structure of type MPI_Status that contains three fields named MPI_SOURCE, MPI_TAG, and MPI_ERROR; the structure *may* contain additional fields.

use:

```
MPI_Get_count(MPI_Status *status, MPI_Datatype datatype, int *count)
```

Comment: I agree. In MSMPI the Microsoft HPC version of MPI there exist a status.count field in which is stored the size in bytes of the incoming message. Fort portability is better to use the standard MPI_Get_count call anyway.

Comment: Accessing the count directly is evil. It violates the MPI standard and will make code non-portable and brittle even when it appears to work.